# How to use the same socket on different pages in react native

Tags: react-native, socket.io, chat

I am using Socket.io for chatting feature in my react-native project. My project is using react native navigation.
But I have trouble things passing Socket.io socket to certain screens. I want to share the socket with the navigation( like a prop I think I'm not sure ).
Currently I'm using Socket.io socketes on each certain screens individually. But this way has some troubles.
The main trouble is that when someone sends me a message I need to know which page I'm on while the app is running.
Does someone have any suggestions on how to do it?
My target is to share the same socket with three pages.
I googled, but couldn't find any suitable results.

```
- AppNavigation.js

import React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


// Chat.
import ChatScreen from '../screens/Chat/ChatScreen';
import VideoChatScreen from '../screens/Chat/VideoChatScreen;


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} options={{ headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="VideoChat" component={VideoChatScreen} options={{ headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;


- ChatScreen.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

class ChatScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
    this.socketClient = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socketClient = SocketIOClient(url);
    this.socketClient.onAny((event, params) => {
      this.onResponseOnSocket(event, params);
    });
  }

  ...


 - VideoChatScreen.js

 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class VideoChatScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
    this.socketClient = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socketClient = SocketIOClient(url);
    this.socketClient.onAny((event, params) => {
      this.onResponseOnSocket(event, params);
    });
  }

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state management tool of your choice to manage a global (App-)State within your app. With functional components I like ContextProvider which is part of RN Core and is still o.k. for class components as long as you have only a few Provider. But many people use Redux or you can use facebooks Recoil which is also an interesting alternative.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

https://recoiljs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think my library will be perfect for your case.
It is the state managment tool dedicated to chat applications: https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat

Your application should be wrapped with ChatProvider component, and you need to create your own service/adapter that will be responsible for websocket connection.

Sending messages, message list, conversations etc. are available in all child components with one hook.